# Excel Reference Cells Up to Number of Characters Until Last Space

Tags: excel, string-length, content-length

I have a cell that is referencing multiple different cells and I want it to reference one more cell at the end that will fill the rest of the space up (up to 80 characters).

Example: Cell AA2 (cell I want to fill up) contains: `=B2&" OEM "&D2&" replacement "&LOWER(LEFT(TRIM(X2),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(X2," ","~",LEN(TRIM(X2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(X2)," ",""))))-1))&" "&LOWER(T2)`

Cell Z2 contains: `582146-01 BDEMS600 MS500CBGB MS525B MS800B`

I want to add the contents of Z2 to the end of AA2 but only until AA2 has 80 characters and I don't want just part of one of the items in Z2. Another thing is I want to do this starting from the end of cell Z2 so let's say 582146-01 and BDEMS600 might get cut off to make it 80 characters. Is this possible? Thanks for the hlep!

Comment: Can you post what your table looks like? It's not very clear what you're asking for.

Comment: what is the value that you have in cell AA2 and Z2 currently. And how do you want the output to be? can you add that too